# Gif is only animating once in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, gif

[image: Gif Image]

I am fetching this gif image from internet and using `CachedNetworkImage` to load image in my flutter application. This image is animating only once. I also tried with `Image.network`. How do I continue the animation infinitely?

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me this gif is set to play only once. Try re-exporting it with loop animation instead.

In other words, it's a gif matter, not flutter matter.